# AWS Lightsail - Wordpress stack - Backup script

Tags: linux, bash, backup

I am regular bitnami wordpress stack user (setting up websites for clients and maintaining it, etc.).

I used to use Updraft backup plugin to backup wordpress and push it to S3 account - however, I found many issues with setup like this.

I figured out that server level backup will be much better.

Here is script I created to take backup of the files, database and then push it to S3 and then check if any files are more than 7 days old and if there are delete it.

**backup_script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
    time=$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H.%M.%S)
    . /home/bitnami/aws_credentials
    /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u DATABASE_USER --password="USER_PASSWORD" --result-file=/home/bitnami/apps/backups/database-$time.sql bitnami_wordpress
    tar -pcf /home/bitnami/apps/backups/database-$time.tar.gz /home/bitnami/apps/backups/database-$time.sql
    tar -pcf /home/bitnami/apps/backups/backup-$time.tar.gz /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress
    find . -name '/home/bitnami/apps/backups/*.sql' -type f -delete
    aws s3 cp /home/bitnami/apps/backups/database-$time.tar.gz s3://maintenance-websites-backups/folder_name/
    aws s3 cp /home/bitnami/apps/backups/backup-$time.tar.gz s3://maintenance-websites-backups/folder_name/
    find /home/bitnami/apps/backups -type f -mtime +7 -delete
```

After run this: `chmod +x /home/bitnami/apps/backup_script.sh`

Setup cronjob to execute script at 1 am everyday:

```
sudo crontab -e

0 1 * * * /home/bitnami/apps/backup_script.sh > /tmp/backup.log 2>&1
```

To push files to S3 AWS CLI is needed.

```
sudo apt-get install awscli
aws configure
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html

**aws_credentials**

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
```

This code is fully working and I haven't encountered any issues so far (4 months running on 10 websites).
However, I wonder how could I restore a backup quickly from such setup?
Ofc, if anyone sees any problems with above code please point it out!